# How to programmatically find the current value of DISPLAY when DISPLAY is unset? (for use in crontab)

Tags: bash, xorg, cron

I have a script that runs via cron to change the desktop wallpaper. I can get it to work by exporting the DISPLAY variable.

But the issue I am concerned about it that the script should work on all systems. **How to find the value of DISPLAY set by the X server without using $DISPLAY?**

So how can I find the correct value for `DISPLAY` programmatically. I can get it to work only when `DISPLAY=:1`. Setting it to `":0"` makes the script exit with

```
No protocol specified
Cannot open display.
```

Comment: If the server is listening on TCP DISPLAY = portnumber - 6000 But ... I doubt cron is smart enough to get this to check for a free port. So you probably need a script to set it.

Comment: UNIX/Linux is an inherently multi-user, multi-session environment: one of the Ubuntu systems I'm currently logged in to has X servers running on displays `:0`, `:2`, and `:5` (and often has more). So first you need to think about what you mean by "the X server"

Comment: This seems a good starting point: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/is-there-a-command-to-list-all-open-displays-on-a-machine

Comment: By the X server I mean the WM and/or the DM instance. I need to change the wallpaper for the desktop. I guess I can use a loop and run the commands on all DISPLAY from 0 through 10?

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind. I found the answer and will be adding an answer here after proper testing.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm using different tools for different DM's. I have got gsettings worked out. I was having the problem with `feh` on i3.

Comment: Ah, I see, will remove my vote :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't for sure. You have to make assumptions.

Pretend you're `cron` and you're facing the worst case scenario for a second: there are multiple users logged in, and each user is running multiple X sessions. You'll have to guess the user (easy enough, we're executing their crontab) and one of that user's X sessions.

If we want to assume the user is running one and only one X session from a tty, and get that session's `$DISPLAY` value we can use `w`:

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user     tty1                      16:32    7:15   0.21s  0.19s -zsh
user     tty2     :1               15:52   48:13   2:17   0.08s /sbin/upstart
user     pts/3    :1               16:19    0.00s  0.66s  0.00s w
```

For example here I'm logged in on tty1, on tty2 (where I'm running an X session) and on pts/3 (the terminal from which I'm running the command).

With a bit of parsing:

```bsh
% w $(id -un) | awk 'NF > 7 && $2 ~ /tty[0-9]+/ {print $3; exit}'
:1
```

So, assuming all the above:

```bsh
0 0 * * * DISPLAY=$(w $(id -un) | awk 'NF > 7 && $2 ~ /tty[0-9]+/ {print $3; exit}') command
```

Will make `cron` execute `command` with `$DISPLAY` set to the first X session running in a tty's `$DISPLAY` value found for the user.

Comment: Well, I guess `cron` is too low level stuff to be handling wallpapers then. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @AshharHasan I think so as well. Perhaps you should demonize a script and let it do the task, it looks both easier and more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

For a more detailed discussion, refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/is-there-a-command-to-list-all-open-displays-on-a-machine

I will simply list the relevant information from that answer here:

There seems to be two simple ways to find the X server instances running on your system.

- `w`:
  The `w` command lists all the open displays. You can then use `awk` to filter out the information you need. The values under `FROM` are the values corresponding to `DISPLAY`.

  ```
  ashhar@xenon:[/tmp/.X11-unix] 
  $ w
  21:18:24 up  3:39,  4 users,  load average: 0.31, 0.27, 0.30
  USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
  ashhar   tty2     :1               17:40    3:39m  6:11   0.08s /usr/bin/dunst
  ashhar   pts/0    :1               17:41    3:36m  0.13s  0.05s vim .i3/config
  ashhar   pts/1    :1               18:07    0.00s  1.44s  0.00s w
  ashhar   pts/2    :1               18:15    9:59   0.79s  0.79s bash
  ```
- Local displays correspond to a socket in `/tmp/.X11-unix`, so we can simply do:

  ```
  cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired on Ashhar Hasan's answer, I would use (tested on Ubuntu 23.04):

```
export DISPLAY=$(
  find /tmp/.X11-unix/ -user $USER -type s -printf "%f" -quit | tr X :
)
```

By filtering by UID, it will work even in presence of multiple logged-in users.

I have a X11wrap.sh script that lets me run X11 application from system scripts, cron, at etc.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

export DISPLAY=$(
      find /tmp/.X11-unix/ -user $USER -type s -printf "%f" -quit | tr X :
)

# For applications that additionally require DBUS.
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus

exec "$@"
```

With it, I can issue the following example, and it will get the X11 system right:

```
echo X11wrap.sh xeyes | at now
```